# php regular expression for dictionary string

Tags: php, regex

I could use some help writing a regular expression for this dictionary string (I don't use them all that often).

This is an example of the string dictionary:

```
O:8:"stdClass":5:{s:4:"sent";i:0;s:6:"graded";i:0;s:5:"score";i:0;s:6:"answer";s:14:"<p>Johnson</p>";s:8:"response";s:0:"";}
```

I want to extract Johnson from the string dictionary.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a PHP [serialized](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) object. Don't use a regular expression. [`unserialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) the data and display the `answer` property accordingly.

```
unserialize($data);
echo $data->answer;
```

Comment: This would be very good if it worked, but the object has been converted to a string.  How do I convert it back to an object?
Note: it was stored in Moodle database as a sting type.

Comment: I understand. It's a PHP serialized string representing an object. My example assumes `$data` holds that string. Check the links I provided for more details.

Comment: Nevermind.  I just needed to assign it to a variable.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'O:8:"stdClass":5:{s:4:"sent";i:0;s:6:"graded";i:0;s:5:"score";i:0;s:6:"answer";s:14:"<p>Johnson</p>";s:8:"response";s:0:"";}';

$obj = unserialize($str);

echo $obj->answer;
```

This would be the correct answer, no regex needed. You may need some additional HTML parsing if you'd want the `<p>` tags removed. If the format will **always** remain the same (and only then!) simply remove the `<p>` and `</p>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be using [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) instead and then you can use preg_match to remove the `<p>` tags.

```
$obj = (unserialize('O:8:"stdClass":5:{s:4:"sent";i:0;s:6:"graded";i:0;s:5:"score";i:0;s:6:"answer";s:14:"<p>Johnson</p>";s:8:"response";s:0:"";}'));
preg_match('~<p>([^<]*)</p>~', $obj->answer, $ans);
print_r($ans[1]); //prints Johnson
```